# ASP.NET Gridview - How to display Headers to the left?

Tags: asp.net

I need to display the column headers to the left within ASP.NET? Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean row headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DetailsView, but it's designed to only show one record (or row) from the datasource in a table like this:

```
Columname1  Value1 
Columname2  Value2
Columname3  Value3
```

Or do you mean you want to align the headertitles to the left? try this:

```
Gridview1.HeaderRow.HorizontalAlign=HorizontalAlign.Left;
```

Comment: Thanks Willem. The DetailsView will do what I need it to do. I just need to display one record. I will just update the bit fields to use labels instead of checkboxes. If my question was good, please vote up

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the alignment on each bound field:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  HeaderText="Source" />
```